# Converting a integral equation to a sum

Tags: integration, summation

I'm writing a paper where I'm calculating Effective Leaf Area Index ($L_e$) from gap fraction data.
A well known formula is as follows:

$L_e=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{-\left[lnP_o\left(\theta\right)\right]cos\theta sin\theta d\theta}$

Where $P_o\left(\theta\right)$ is the gap fraction dependent on the viewing angle.

But our measurements are done in 4.5 degree (0.0785 radian) increments and we calculate the $L_e$ as a sum. I wrote the equation as follows but I'm not sure if I wrote it right and if I should change it in order to be more clear that the sum follows $P_o$ values in 0.0785 radian increments.

$L_e=2\ast\sum_{\theta=0.0785}^{1.5708}{-\left[lnP_o\left(\theta\right)\right]cos\theta sin\theta\ast0.0785}$

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is defined as the Riemann sum

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x_n^*)\Delta x_n
$$

where $\Delta x_n = x_{n}-x_{n-1}$ and $x_n^*\in[x_{n-1},x_n]$. If $N$ is a large number, you can approximate

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\approx\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x_n^*)\Delta x_n
$$

As applied to your case:

$$
L_e\approx -2\Delta\theta\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ln{P(\theta_n)}\cos\theta_n\sin\theta_n
$$

where $\Delta\theta=0.0785~\mbox{rad}$ is the constant angular resolution of your instrument and $\{\theta_n\}$ are your measured angles. Hope this helps!